# Problemas com Pseudo-classes em tag Label

Tags: css, css-hover

É possível aplicar efeitos de `:hover`, `:active` e `:focus` na tag `Label` inteiro? não estou conseguindo pois o efeito só aplica no `content` do label...

```css
body{
  font-family:Helvetica,Arial;
}
.collapse{
  margin-top: 50px;
  transition:all .5s;
  opacity:0;
}

label:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
label:focus{
    background-color: yellow;
}
label:active{
  background-color: red;
}

label:before{
    content: "Generic button";
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #CCC;
}
#do-collapse{
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
}
#do-collapse:checked ~ .collapse{  
  margin-top:10px;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="do-collapse"/> 
<label for="do-collapse"></label>
<div class="collapse">
  Something
</div>
```

Comment: **Removi** minha resposta justamente porque já havia uma pergunta semelhante.

Comment: alem de não ter resposta, não consigo ver onde a pergunta é parecida com a minha

Comment: Basta colocar em seu código: `label:hover:before`, `label:focus:before`, `label:active:before` ... Como está  na resposta da pergunta citada.